# Postgresql9.3 select query showing error

Tags: postgresql

Below DB query is showing below error on postgresql9.3.

```
SELECT '\'' || t2.name || '\'', '\'' || t1.phone_number || '\'', '\'' || t1.details || '\'', '\'' || t1.description || '\'', '\'' || (CASE WHEN t1.s_id IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE t3.s_type END) || '\'', '\'' || t1.s_id || '\'' FROM abc_tble AS t1 LEFT JOIN pqrtable AS t2 ON t1.s_id = nid LEFT JOIN te AS t3 ON t1.s_id = t3.s_id;
```

Invalid command \''. Try \? for help.

But Above query is working fine in postgresql8.3.

Answer (score 1):

> *But above query is working fine in Postgres 8.3.*

The SQL standard defines two single quotes to escape one inside a literal: `''''`

Postgres 8.3 defaulted to a non-standard behavior where it was allowed to escape a single quote using a backslash: `'\''`

This deviation from the SQL standard was always discouraged and can be controlled through the configuration parameter [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS)

With version 9.1 the default for this parameter was changed from `off` to `on`. Version 8.1 and later would emit a warning when you used the non-standard way of escaping single quotes (unless you explicitly turned that off)

Comment: Yes, problem has resolved after changing ''''. Thanks for your support.        How to change standard_conforming_strings value of postgresql.conf? I have checked but this option is not found in postgresql.conf.

Comment: @yogesh. In a default generated postgresql.conf that setting **is** there somewhere near the end of the file. But I would not recommend changing that. Use standard compliant SQL instead.